# capistrano-unicorn error on deploy - chmod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, setup-deployment, unicorn

I'm just trying to move to the new server with one of my apps, so i'm setting up capistrano with capistrano-unicorn to deploy code.

I've used [gem details](https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn) to set things up.
But i get an error (and a rollback afterwards) which i fail to connect with unicorn or capistrano settings.
the error as follows:

```
* executing "chmod -R -- g+w \\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242 && rm -rf -- 

\\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242/public/system && mkdir -p -- \\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242/public/ && ln -s -- ~/www/elmor.org.ua/shared/system \\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242/public/system && rm -rf -- \\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242/log && ln -s -- ~/www/elmor.org.ua/shared/log \\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242/log && rm -rf -- \\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- \\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242/tmp/ && ln -s -- ~/www/elmor.org.ua/shared/pids \\~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["elmor.org.ua"]
    [elmor.org.ua] executing command
 ** [out :: elmor.org.ua] chmod: ���������� �������� ������ � �~/www/elmor.org.ua/releases/20130218122242�: ��� ������ ����� ��� �������
    command finished in 73ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

How can i fix this error? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a gem error, now it's getting fixed